# Strong induction. What is responsible for basis step?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

I have no problems with weak induction. There is a basis step and inductive step. But it seems that basis step is missing in the strong induction. It says that$$(\forall n[  \forall m<n, P(m)\implies P(n)]) \implies \forall n P(n))$$ If it is true, then we can proof that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} (n<n)$ which can't be true. We have $P(m)$ which says that $1<1, 2<2,...,(n-1)<(n-1)$. From here we can construct implication by adding $n-m$ to the all inequalities $m<m$ s.t. $m<n$. So we have $n<n$.

Comment: P(0) is vacuously true.

Comment: Why can't we use the same trick for getting rid from basis step of weak induction? Firstly we show that $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$. Then since P(-1) is vacuously true, P(0) is also true.

Comment: No, we actually need to show that P(0) is true in weak and strong induction, both. What I meant to say is that in the hypothesis to the left of the implication in the statement of strong induction, the truth of P(0) is implicitly incorporated in a vacuous manner.

Comment: But the truth of P(0) is also implicitly incorporated in weak induction. If we show that $\forall n P(n-1)\implies P(n)$ then taking $n=0$ we have $P(-1)\implies P(0)$. Since P(-1) is vacuously true then P(0) is also true.

Comment: I think you are a bit mistaken. This n ranges over 0,1,2,... , i.e. what you actually show, is that if for some n = 1,2,3, ... , if P(n-1) is true, then P(n) is true, and separately, that P(0) is true. Because, although what you have said (P(-1) is vacuously true) is correct, you never show that "if P(n-1) is true then so is P(n)" for n=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a base case is automatically included in the strong induction hypothesis. Indeed, it applies to well-ordered sets; if $0$ is the minimal element of $X$, then by specializing the hypothesis "if $P(m)$ is true 
for all $m\in X$ with $m <_X n$, then $P(n)$ is also true" to the $n= 0$ case, we automatically obtain that $P(0)$ is true. (Note that a "for all $x$ which satisfies $P$,$\dotsc$" statement is vacuously true if there is no such $x$ that satisfies the property $P$.)

A subtle, you assume the consecuence $n<n$ from the strong hypothesis. But it is false, we kown  that $n<n$ is false. So we have not proven the implication.